# My application keeps crashing when I hit the back button and if the myLocationEnabled is true

Tags: flutter

I am working with navigation using flutter but my app keeps crashing if I hit the back button and the myLocationEnabled is equals to true, but if I set its value to false the crashing issue will be gone. So I came up with an idea to use WillPop to set its value to false if I hit the back button, but after doing that it crashes again. can anyone check if my logic is right.

here's the message in the terminal after crashing

F/libc (15924): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 16574 (GLThread 7795), pid 15924 (example.project)

Build fingerprint: 'Redmi/lancelot_global/lancelot:10/QP1A.190711.020/V12.0.4.0.QJCMIXM:user/release-keys'

```
        bool location = true;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            setState(() {
              location = false;
            });
            return true;
          },
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Restaurants Map'),
            ),
            body: SafeArea(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
                    child: MapboxMap(
                      accessToken: dotenv.env['MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN'],
                      initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
                      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                      onStyleLoadedCallback: _onStyleLoadedCallback,
                      //if this is false it will not crash if I tap the back button
                      myLocationEnabled: location,
                      myLocationTrackingMode: MyLocationTrackingMode.TrackingGPS,
                      minMaxZoomPreference: const MinMaxZoomPreference(14, 17),
                    ),
                  ),
                  CarouselSlider(
                      items: carouselItems,
                      options: CarouselOptions(
                          height: 105,
                          viewportFraction: 0.6,
                          initialPage: 0,
                          enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          onPageChanged:
                              (int index, CarouselPageChangedReason reason) {
                            setState(() {
                              pageIndex = index;
                            });
                            _addSourceAndLineLayer(index, true);
                          }))
                ],
              ),
            ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                controller.animateCamera(
                    CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(_initialCameraPosition));
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.my_location),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

Comment: what is the crash all about? could you include the error message?

Comment: this is the error messageF/libc (15924): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 16574 (GLThread 7795), pid 15924 (example.project)

Build fingerprint: 'Redmi/lancelot_global/lancelot:10/QP1A.190711.020/V12.0.4.0.QJCMIXM:user/release-keys'

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code. use `MapboxMap` class with the following property.

```
MapboxMap(
          myLocationRenderMode: MyLocationRenderMode.GPS,
          myLocationTrackingMode: MyLocationTrackingMode.TrackingGPS,
          accessToken: dotenv.env['MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN'],
          initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          onStyleLoadedCallback: _onStyleLoadedCallback,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
        );
```

Comment: the crashing is not fixed though, but thank you for this

Comment: Your code is incomplete can you please post the full code?

Comment: basically, this is sort of same code as mine "https://github.com/Imperial-lord/mapbox-flutter/tree/main/basic_nav/completed_code/mapbox_navigation", but in this code when you go to other page it sometimes crashes if you toggle the screen back and fort.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely related to the [Native crash in Flutter 3 #1119](https://github.com/flutter-mapbox-gl/maps/issues/1119) issue, which is still open...